# Swift: checking if on Wifi or Cellular network & detect network speed?

Tags: ios, swift, cellular-network

I am wondering if there is an easy way to find out if a user is on wifi or cellular data (perhaps CoreTelephony)?

I am mainly interested in just actual network speed to determine the level of quality of video I should set for AVPLayer (via preferredPeakBitRate).

Answer (score -2):

there are two steps involved. First detect what type of network are you on.
second is what is the bandwidth. There are two functions below to perform each task

This function is to identify the network you are on.

```
enum ReachabilityType: CustomStringConvertible {
case wwan
case wiFi
var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .wwan: return "WWAN"
    case .wiFi: return "WiFi"
    }
}
```

}

This function is to get the bandwidth speed.

```
func bandWidthCheck()  {
let sample = URL(string: "http:exampleURL")
let request = URLRequest(url: sample!)
let session = URLSession.shared
let startTime = Date()
let task =  session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, resp, error) in
    guard error == nil && data != nil else{
        print("connection error or data is nill")
        return
    }
    guard resp != nil else{
        print("response is nill")
        return
    }
    let size  = CGFloat( (resp?.expectedContentLength)!) / 1000000.0
    print(size)

    let time = CGFloat( Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime))
    print("elapsed: \(time)")
    print("Speed: \(size/time) Mb/sec")
}
task.resume()
```

}

Comment: I would steer away from testing the user's connectivity by consuming data.  You should measure a ping or something else that won't make your app a data user.